# JSON.parse not working for valid json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am using the below line in Javascript to parse a json string.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"respDataMap":{"userMessages":{"lbSearchHint":"Enteravalueandpress\"Enter\"orclickon\"Search\"#"}},"respErrorCode":"","respErrorMessage":""}');
```

The escaped double-quote character in the string is causing the json parsing to fail.
But, the same string pasted in online JSON validators is certified as valid.
How do I fix this?

Comment: At the time of asking this, I thought double backslash also didn't work. (This was because i was trying to replace single slash with a double slash in Java. Unfortunately my Java replaceAll usage was wrong leading me to think double backslash wasn't working in JS)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double slash like for escape character

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"respDataMap":{"userMessages":{"lbSearchHint":"Enteravalueandpress\\"Enter\\"orclickon\\"Search\\"#"}},"respErrorCode":"","respErrorMessage":""}');
```

Comment: Thanks. Triple-backslash is also working.. why's that?

Comment: Javascript interpreter will interprate three as as combination  of double  '\\' and single  '\' which is interpreted as one '\'.
'\\\' == '\\'+'\' ==  '\\' == '\'@Teddy

And double slash also  interpreter to single salsh ‘\\’  ==   ‘\’